# Timestamp without time zone error in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

While converting oracle to PostgreSQL I'm getting error like
*function trunc(timestamp without time zone) does not exist*
I have tried for both clock_timestamp(),current_timestamp() both not working.
timestamp without time zone

**BENMAST_CR_ON** is in timestamp without time zone

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM BENMAST WHERE BENMAST_ENTITY_CODE =$1 AND
                        BENMAST_CUSTOMER_CODE =$2 AND TRUNC(BENMAST_CR_ON) = TRUNC($3)'
      INTO W_BEN_ACT_COUNT
      USING P_ENTITY_CODE, P_CUST_CODE, SYSDATE;
```

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) it must be `date_trunc()`. Additionally: there is no `sysdate` function in Postgres

Comment: Unrelated, but: why are you using dynamic SQL here? That seems completely useless.  (Btw: `count(*)` would be slightly faster than `count(1)`)

Comment: Sorry i have given count(*) still not working

Comment: BENMAST_CUSTOMER_CODE =$2 AND DATE_TRUNC('day', BENMAST_CR_ON::timestamp without time zone) = DATE_TRUNC('day', current_timestamp(0)::timestamp without time zone)'
   i have tried like this still not working

Comment: "not working" is not a valid Postgres error message. If you only want to compare the date (without time), why not just use  `AND BENMAST_CR_ON::date = current_date`